How enable CORS in api gateway aws
I’m setting up an API using AWS API Gateway and Lambda, and I’m facing CORS issues when making requests from my frontend. While reviewing the setup, I noticed something odd:
In the Triggers section of the Lambda configuration (where the API Gateway endpoints are listed), the CORS field shows NO, even though I enabled CORS in the API Gateway configuration for each method.
My CORS setup in API Gateway:

My CORS setup in Lambda:
export const handler = async (event, context) => {
  let body;
  let response;
  let statusCode = 200;
  const headers = {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://www.yoteinvito.com",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Accept",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials":"true",
  };

Triggers configuration in Lambda:
Triggers configuration in Lambda
Headers in frontend:
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(formData),  
    })



Error in Console:
Access to fetch at 'https://rgfz15v2qp.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dev/confirmations' from origin 'https://www.yoteinvito.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
Is it normal for API Gateway to show CORS: NO in the endpoint details?
Could this be the reason for my CORS issues?
Are there any additional steps I need to take to ensure that CORS is fully enabled?
I’d appreciate any guidance or experiences you can share. Thank you!
I enabled CORS in API Gateway for all methods (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.), added the necessary headers (e.g., Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *), and configured responses for OPTIONS requests.
However, despite these configurations, the CORS field still shows NO in the trigger details, and my frontend requests fail with CORS errors.

The screenshot of your API Gateway config shows a trailing slash in the field corresponding to the allowed origin. No valid Web origin contains a trailing slash; remove that trailing slash.

This question is similar to: Access from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked even though I've allowed https://example.com/. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Your pre-flight method is failing, which is the OPTIONS method of your API. Be sure to enable cors and deploy your changes to stage.
If it still fails try a wildcard to make sure the issue isn't related to your host url.

Since you're an AWS employee: if you have any power to influence UX, you should encourage AWS to validate their users' CORS configurations. The portal could have detected and reported that https://www.yoteinvito.com/ is not a valid Web origin, which would have saved the OP precious time. Here is some advice about implementing CORS middleware, some of which applies to portals like AWS's: https://jub0bs.com/posts/2023-02-08-fearless-cors/
